# Creating LinkedNotebooks from API

Tags: javascript, node.js, evernote

I am working with the Evernote api trying to make linked notebooks from within our web application.

We are using evernote-sdk-js version of the API.

We are able to create the Shared Notebook from the API.  Also we are able to create a Linked Notebook and receive a valid response.  The problem is the linked notebook is not working.  The notebook is returned in the ListLinkedNotebook api call but when I try to authorize it I receive an error.

```
Error { identifier: 'SharedNotebook.id', key: 'xxxx' }
```

From what I've read means the notebook is no longer shared by the owner.  This is not true as the owner account still shows the pending request in the 'share' window.

Here is the logical flow:

1) User enters email address of the person they wish to share notebook with. A request is made to our server to create a ShareNotebook.

We create a Shared Notebook like this: (From Owner Account)

```
  var notebook = new Evernote.SharedNotebook();
  notebook.notebookGuid = guid;
  notebook.email = email;
  notebook.privilege = Evernote.SharedNotebookPrivilegeLevel.FULL_ACCESS;

  var userclient = new Evernote.Client({token: token, sandbox: sandbox});
  var notestore = userclient.getNoteStore();
  notestore.createSharedNotebook(userclient.token, notebook, function(err, results){
      callback(err, results);
  });
```

With an example response like:

```
{
 allowPreview:null
 email:"...@gmail.com"
 id:12345
 notebookGuid:"d2fa3cbe-...."
 notebookModifiable:false
 privilege:4
 recipientSettings:null
 requireLogin:null
 serviceCreated:1469079222000
 serviceUpdated:1469079222000
 shareKey:"xxxx-sxxx"
 userId:999xxxxx
 username:null
}
```

2) Since Evernote doesn't send an email from the API request we manually send the user a link to activate the Shared Notebook.

Code to create LinkedNotebook: (From Shared User Account)

```
  var notebook = new Evernote.LinkedNotebook;
  notebook.shareName = options.shareName;
  notebook.username = options.username;
  notebook.shardId = options.shardId;
  notebook.shareKey = options.shareKey;

  var userclient = new Evernote.Client({token: token, sandbox: sandbox});
  var notestore = userclient.getNoteStore();
  notestore.createLinkedNotebook(userclient.token, notebook, function(err, results){
      callback(err, results);
  });
```

And the example response:

```
{ 
 shareName: 'Notebook Name',
 username: '...',
 shardId: 'sxxx',
 shareKey: 'xxxx-sxxx',
 uri: null,
 guid: '4f8df3c2-...',
 updateSequenceNum: 630,
 noteStoreUrl: 'https://www.evernote.com/shard/sxxx/notestore',
 webApiUrlPrefix: 'https://www.evernote.com/shard/sxxx/',
 stack: null,
 businessId: null
}
```

Has anyone had any luck creating a Linked Notebook from the API?  It seems like the createLinkedNotebook API call is not working correctly.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr you can't do what you're trying to do right now, sorry.

So there are a couple pieces missing here, not something you can do much about.

The first piece is that the shared notebook must be "claimed" by a user (the recipient), during which it gets assigned to the user. Until it's claimed, a LinkedNotebook pointing to the SharedNotebook won't actually give you access to the underlying Notebook - [authenticateToSharedNotebook](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_authenticateToSharedNotebook) will fail.

The second piece is the shareKey itself. We renamed the struct member you see as `shareKey` to `globalId` on the SharedNotebook and `sharedNotebookGlobalId` on the LinkedNotebook - we're currently in the process of updating our developer documentation, and then we'll update the sdks. To "claim" a sharedNotebook, the recipient needs to call `authenticateToSharedNotebook` with the shareKey, not the globalId. The catch is that we don't expose a method to generate the real shareKey, so there's no way for third-party clients to generate this and join the shared notebook. Once it *is* claimed, you can call authenticateToSharedNotebook with the globalId to get access to the notebook.

There's a `shareNotebook` method we added that send an email as part of the API call. That email contains a link for the user to click on which contains the shareKey and allows claiming a SharedNotebook, but that isn't currently in the SDKs or documented. We'll hopefully get it up with this round of doc updates.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It would be nice to have a message next to these api calls, simply "3rd party apps can't use this api call at the moment".

Comment: Which call specifically? _Technically_ you can use all the calls, eg you can create a LinkedNotebook to any SharedNotebook, including a SharedNotebook that is already assigned to you. I agree it's not super useful though, hoping to change that soon!

Comment: One other api call we were hoping to take advantage of was "sendMessageToSharedNotebookMembers" but this too seem limited or not working from 3rd party api.  Anyways, I look forward to testing out the new features when the SDKs and docs are updated.

Comment: FYI, just added the shareNotebook docs at https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_shareNotebook, although it's not in any of the SDKs yet. The JS sdk is first on my list...

Comment: @akhaku looks like `shareNotebook` method does not send an email. I've tried to call it from php-sdk, by cloning `createCharedNotebook` method and changing it a little. It returns me a _sharedNotebook_ object, and in web interface it displays that notebook shared, but no email was sent to recipient. Tried it in sandbox

Comment: Hi Tony. I just dug through the code and it looks like we explicitly don't allow sending emails using the Evernote service (including this shareNotebook email) for all third party tokens (including Developer tokens). Essentially there's nothing you can do at this time. We need to figure out a way to make this accessible to clients - hopefully we get time to do that soon...

Comment: Ok, but you wrote in the answer that you introduce a `shareNotebook` _method which will send an email as part of the API call_. Correct me if I wrong, but doesn't it mean that when I call `shareNotebook` method it will share a notebook and then send an email to a recipient of the share in one API call ?

Comment: I did, yes - I was wrong. shareNotebook will not currently send an email when a third party developer calls it (it does when we call it internally with our API keys). Sorry about that. We'll look into ways to get this to work, either by allowing it to send an email if called using a developer token or third party token, or some other way to get what you want.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thank you for answers and making it clear )

Comment: @Tony update: we just deployed code that should enable the shareNotebook email for when it's called by third party developers. Note that no email will be sent if the shared notebook already exists (contrary to what the docs say right now).

Comment: And for posterity, the docs have been updated to reflect the method behavior.